# Limit font face to certain language

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a magical way that could make font to support certain language and other languages to follow sequence font-family: fonts;

Comment: Show your markup and current CSS, please.

Comment: `@font-face` rules have a [unicode-range property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#descdef-unicode-range), so you could claim all the other fonts don't have the glyphs you need, but that doesn't let you tell different latin scripts from one another, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

*[lang=jp] {
  font-family: Meiryo;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello!</p>

<p lang="jp">こんにちわ！</p>
```

Comment: I think you mean こんにちわ.

Comment: I am looking to make the way without assigning attribute. Auto configure language, maybe

Comment: Well you can't make CSS recognize the language, that's not how it works. CSS is designed to be declarative, so you have to create your markup accordingly. Using the `lang` attribute is probably the most semantic way to do that. You could use Javascript to set that attribute though. In that case you would have to guess the language in script, which has a good chance of either going wrong or crippling your ability to intermix characters from multiple scripts in the same paragraph. I would try to avoid going down the script route and try the declarative approach instead.